# Connection refused when calling ingress from pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I'm running a .NET 5 API application on Kubernetes as well as Identity Server in separate pods on my laptop using Docker Desktop. Both applications are made available for consumers using the nginx ingress controller. When I call the ingress in the browser from outside of the cluster, it works well. Also, when I run the API from Visual Studio, the connection to Identity Server via the ingress is successful.

But when I deploy the API to Kubernetes, the pod that runs the API can't connect to the ingress. The API uses the ingress to call Identity Server because it has to happen over https. SSL is terminated by the ingress and forwarding traffic to the pods over http.
The ingress address to IdentityServer is https://k8s-local.com/identityserver. From the API pod, the DNS is known; when I execute a ping, it goes ok. When I perform a curl command to this address from the pod, I'm getting a Connection Refused error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to k8s-local.com port 443: Connection refused
```

How do I make the ingress DNS available to the pods?

This is what my ingress.yml looks like:

```yaml
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: my-ingress
 spec:
   tls:
   - hosts:
     - k8s-local.com
     secretName: local-tls
   rules:
   - host: k8s-local.com
     http:
       paths:
       - pathType: Prefix
         path: /identityserver/
         backend:
           service:
             name: identityserver-service
             port:
               number: 5000

       - pathType: Prefix
         path: /customer-api/
         backend:
           service:
             name: customer-api-service
             port:
               number: 5000
```

This is what I get when I run `kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx`:

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.109.3.50     localhost     80:31964/TCP,443:32210/TCP   11d
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.105.158.51   <none>        443/TCP                      11d
```

And `kubectl get ingress`:

```
NAME                     CLASS    HOSTS                          ADDRESS     PORTS     AGE
my-ingress               <none>   k8s-local.com                  localhost   80, 443   6d11h
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes, I had to update my local hosts file. The IP of the ingress DNS had to match the load balancer IP. I updated Docker Desktop locally, my config was not correct anymore.